# Custom attribute Show in order summary on shipping page but disappear on paymeny page

Tags: orders, summary

I have add custom attribute in order summary, it show on checkout first page (#shipping) when shipping method select and go for second page of checkout (#payment) then custom attribute disappear.
I am render custom attribute by using after plugin of this method `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider::getConfig`
my code is

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlugCOnfig" type="Magerex\Configurator\Plugin\Cart\Summary\DefaultConfigProvider" />
    </type>
    </config>
```

> Magerex\Configurator\Plugin\Cart\Summary\DefaultConfigProvider

namespace Magerex\Configurator\Plugin\Cart\Summary;

```
class DefaultConfigProvider extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
        $Quote = $result['quoteItemData'];
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($items as $idx => $item) {
            $configOption = null;
//            foreach ($Quote as $quoteItem) {
            $decodeJson = json_decode($Quote[$index]['configurator_params'], true);
            $index++;
            if (isset($decodeJson["productDetails"])) {
                foreach ($decodeJson['productDetails']  as $key => $value) {
                    if ($key == 'productImage') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $configOption.= $key. " : " .$value .' ';
                }
            }
            $items[$idx]['configurator'] = $configOption;
        }

//        }

        // Update the  current items array
        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

> requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/summary/item/details.html':
                'Magerex_Configurator/template/summary/item/details.html'
        }
    }
};
```

Add this line in

> details.html

```
<span class="c-minicart__highlight" data-bind="text: $parent.configurator"> </span>
```

> Screenshot for shipping page

[image]

> Screenshot second page of checkout  #payment page

.

[image]

Please anyone know what the mistake i did, guid me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the ajax request '***shipping-information***' when we click 'next' from the checkout/# shipping page to go to checkout /# payment.
This request returns payment_methods and totals. In 'totals', there are the attributes of the items that are the result of filtering according to the attributes declared in the TotalsItemInterface interface. Then Knockout syncs this returned data and the custom attributes you declared will disappear.

To solve this problem we must add setters and getters of the custom attribute in *Quote/Api/Data/TotalsItemInterface* and in the *Quote/Model/ Cart/Totals/Item* class, which implements the interface.

Attention: Do not modify the core files directly. This solution is only a confirmation of what I have said above.